# Split function not working in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

what i Need :

- Split the string.
- i Need first Character from the String.
- if the string certain character limit i like to show only first name not by(...).

  ```
   ex: ankit mishra pandit aggarwaal.

   - so i just want  only ankit.

   - if its is ankit mishra its ok.

   * otherwise show Full Name.
  ```

Here is the twig code:

```
           {%if item.metadata.name |length < 20 %}
            {% set foo = item.metadata.name|split(',') %}

            {{ foo[0] }}

            {%else%}{{WordLimit(item.metadata.name,20,10)}} ..
               {%endif%}
```

output im getting :

```
  Deepak Singh.
```

- i have refer Source: Twig Split filter http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html.
- where i have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to write a twig extension.
See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

```
class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('first_word', array($this, 'first_word')),
        );
    }

    public function first_word($word)
    {
        $words = explode(' ', $word);
        $first_word = $words[0];
        ...
        return $first_word;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_extension';
    }
}
```

And if your twig file :

```
{{item.metadata.name | first_word }}
```

Comment: thank you this is the most perfect answer cheers it worked thank you very much sr